# Wordpress revolution slider does not show up on the mobile version

Tags: wordpress

I'm really stuck here... In the revolution slider menu, everything is set to 'ON' for mobile devices, etc. It should be showing up but it doesn't. There's something in the code somewhere, I'm sure. Not much a coder but I would very much appreciate a little help from you guys if you know the answer. Much appreciate it!
This is the site:  *RESOLVED

Comment: .wpb_column.vc_column_container.vc_col-sm-12.vc_hidden-xs {
 display: block !important;
}

Comment: add this in style.css or your theme css

Comment: Thank you, good sir, you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your site link, I have checked you have added revolution slider with visual composer.

In visual composer columns settings, you have set hide for mobile.

please check your visual composer columns settings.

Comment: You are totally right. God, I love this website. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here i am sent screens shot of VC class.
http://prntscr.com/jselba